# Mic doesn't work during calls!

Tags: calls, microphone, speaker, huawei-u8860

I have Honor 3C.

My phone records sounds, in sound recorder app or capturing video with camera.
But when I call someone (or someone calls me) mic doesn't work unless I enable speaker. When it's on speaker, the mic works!!!

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that your phone has two mics - one for "computer-like" use, one for when you're holding it to your face - and the second of these is broken (i.e. a hardware problem). If that's right, then you should get it repaired, either by taking it back to the shop, or by finding a repair centre near you.

Comment: It was a hardware problem with the second mic.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary fix is to put it on speaker then back to internal mic I've had this problem with three different phones all different name brands.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to -> Settings -> APPS -> Permissions -> Microphone -> When Recorder is enabled, disable it.

If this does not work, you can try to disable all other checkmarks *"screenshot it first"*, if none of this has helped, you have to contact a repair service.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue before. And I solved. The mic is controlled by other apps during your call. Just deny apps having permissions to use microphone and phone.
Go to settings-apps-all apps-tap each app, check it's permissions and deny microphone and phone.
Ofcourse don't deny for apps like whatsapp, skype etc.